# SWIG with Eigen3::Vector3d and std::vector<Vector3d>

Tags: python, c++, swig, eigen, eigen3

The corresponding gist is [here](https://gist.github.com/nschloe/5e213272671db5dd745508093f37a4a1).

---

I'd like to use SWIG to call a bunch of C++ function from Python, specifically functions that accept vectors. So far, I've implemented it all with `std_vector.i` and `std::vector<double>`, but since I end of converting it all into `Eigen::Vector3d` anyways, I thought I might better make it native. A small C++ example is

```
#ifndef MYTEST_HPP
#define MYTEST_HPP

#include <iostream>
#include <Eigen/Dense>

void
print_norm(const Eigen::Vector3d & x) {
  std::cout << x.norm() << std::endl;
}

void
print_norms(const std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d> & xs) {
  for (const auto & x: xs) {
      std::cout << x.norm() << std::endl;
  }
}

#endif // MYTEST_HPP
```

I have no idea though how to best call this from Python. Perhaps

```
import mytest

a = [1, 1, 0]
mytest.print_norm(a)
```

this is reasonable? A `numpy.array` might also work. Either way, I have no idea what to put in my `mytest.i`.

Any hints?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few examples of wrapping Eigen types with NumPy floating around on the web, where the [Biomechanical Toolkit](https://github.com/Biomechanical-ToolKit/BTKCore/blob/master/Utilities/SWIG/eigen.i) implementation is the most widely copied, and I would recommend using that one too. It looks relatively big, but that's mostly from all the sanity checks and separate templates for different types.

Conversion from NumPy to Eigen works by using the `obj_to_array_contiguous_allow_conversion` function from the accompanying [`numpy.i`](https://github.com/Biomechanical-ToolKit/BTKCore/blob/master/Utilities/SWIG/numpy.i), followed by `PyArray_DATA` to get the data as a contiguous C(++) array, from which the data is simply assigned to each coefficient in the Eigen matrix separately.

The other way around is pretty much the inverse: a python NumPy array is created with `PyArray_SimpleNew`, which is filled with data from the Eigen matrix.

It doesn't directly do the wrapping for `std::vector<Eigen::Vector3d>`, you can set that up using `%include <stl.i>` probably, but in my experience it would be better to use Nx3 numpy arrays as lists of 3D vectors, because of the issues with Eigen, alignment and STL containers.